# Extracting characters from a string and putting into specific arrays by type

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm new to Java so I'm trying to write random programs to figure it out. I'm trying to write something that takes as user-input a quadratic equation like so: `x^2 + 3x -1`

Maybe this is too advanced (or maybe it isn't) but I'm wondering how to extract the characters one-by-one in a loop. If it was all digits I think I could use `.isDigit()` and save them to an array, but because they're different data types I'm not sure how to go about doing this. My 'code' so far looks like this

```
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.StringBuffer;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Character;

public class Lab
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please input the quadratic equation (ex: 2x^2 + 3x - 2): ");

        String request = user_input.nextLine();
            int myArr[];
        String lettArr[];
        for (int i = 0; i <= request.length(); i++)
        {
            String c = request.charAt(i);

            if (request.isDigit(c))
            {
                myArr[1] += c;
            }
            if(request.isLowerCase(c))
            {
                lettArr[1] += c;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(myArr[0]);
    }
}
```

my `.isDigit()` and `.isLowerCase()` methods are not working. I think I'm using them in the right sense. This is pretty complex for my level and I'm wondering if this is a dead-end or an acceptable strategy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what your are trying to do is to extract the coefficients from the user input. Your approach might work but there would be many case that you have to consider (+/- signs for example). Instead why don't you try Java's regular expressions

```
String input = "2x^2 - 4x + 1";
input = input.replaceAll("\\s", ""); //removes  all whitespaces

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(-?\\d+)x\\^2((\\+|-)\\d+)x((\\+|-)\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

if (!m.matches()) {
    System.out.println("Incorrect input");
    return;
}

int a, b, c;
a = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
b = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
c = Integer.parseInt(m.group(4));

System.out.println(String.format("a=%d, b=%d, c=%d", a, b, c));
```

You can adapt this fragment and use it in your code. I , however, supposed that your coefficients are integer numbers. If you need them, instead, to be `double` you have to change the format of the given regex and also to change `Integer.parseInt` to `Double.parseDouble`. I could write this in more details if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with your code:

```
public class Lab
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please input the quadratic equation (ex: 2x^2 + 3x - 2): ");

        String request = user_input.nextLine();
        int myArr[];        //not initialized
        String lettArr[];   //should be a character type & not initialized
        for (int i = 0; i <= request.length(); i++)
        {
            String c = request.charAt(i); // returns a char

            if (request.isDigit(c))
            {
                myArr[1] += c;  // not right, myArr is ints and c is a char
            }
            if(request.isLowerCase(c))
            {
                lettArr[1] += c; // not right
            }
        }
        System.out.println(myArr[0]); //only prints one char (you might want this
     }
 }
```

1.
You are extracting a character from the input string and trying to add it to the second entry in an uninitialized array. You're line in code is:

```
myArr[1] += c;
```

myArr is an integer array and c is a character. You can't do that in java. What's more, you are trying to add a char to an int, which was not initialized in the first place!! The type of everything in an array must be the same. This gets more complicated when it comes to inheritance and such, but for now just know that you can't do that. If you wanted the Integer value of a character you can use:

```
Integer.parseInt(c)
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with your statement, but I'm 90% sure that it's not trying to do what you want it to. For reference:

```
myCharArr[i] = c;
```

assigns the i-th element (starting from 0) to the value of c. So if i=1 and myCharArr was initialized to 3 elements long, it would look like this:

```
[ ? | c | ?]
```

where ? is just a garbage value.

2.
In java you need to initialize your arrays, or use a more dynamic List object. The thing with primitive arrays is that their size cannot change, i.e. when an primitive array is initialized:

```
int arr[] = new int[5];
```

it stays the same size (in this case 5). If you use something like an ArrayList, you can add as many things as you want. The way you would initialize ArrayLists would be like:

```
ArrayList<Integer> intArr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Character> charArr = new ArrayList<Character();
```

and with those initialized you can do:

```
intArr.add(someInt);  
charArr.add(someChar);
```

You can use primitive arrays for this problem but it will save you a bit of trouble if you use Lists.

Read up on arrays.